# Multifunction canon MG2520 printer installed scanner not detected

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, scanner

I have been through I can't even remember all the edits. Yet my scanner is not detected. Used all the efforts names and this printer scanner is supported yet there fails to be a **comprehensible guide to add the backend gdits etc**.  How do you install a Canon MG2520 with a scanner?